# Memory Limit difference between PHPINFO and Readiness Check!

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, memory

when I execute phpinfo() it says 2000M, but when i run Readiness Check it give me 128M... what I have to do?

[image: phpinfo()]

[image]

I don't understand where it takes this value, is there any way to skip this check? I tried to edit the PhpReadinessCheck.php file but it doesn't work, maybe I have to refresh something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 3 ways to change that value: using `.htaccess`, using `php.ini`, set value in php code.

You should review your `index.php` or `app/bootstrap.php`, maybe you will find this code `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M')`. Remove it.

If the problem is not resolved, try adding this `ini_set('memory_limit', '768M')` to your `index.php`.

**The final solution:**

Refresh the Magento crontab (is the configuration used to run Magento cron jobs for setup application) by running this command at Magento root folder:

```
bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Comment: If i add ini_set('memory_limit', '768M') to my index.php when I print phpinfo() the new value is the value I set... but in the Readiness Check it give me always 128M!

Comment: @GianniPasquali try open entire Mgaento project in Netbeans and find the string "memory_limit" in all the files inside it.Your problem is so weird!

Comment: I tryed but it found a lot of files, the weird thing is that looking for "128M" string it finds nothing, it find the string in "/var/.setup_cronjob_status" file where there is the alert message...

I also modified the "PhpReadinessCheck.php" file in "setup\src\Magento\Setup" dir changing the alert message  but by changing that text it does not change in the ReadinessCheck, perhaps after modifying that file should be done some operation via SSH?

PS sorry for my english XD

Comment: @GianniPasquali You're doing it right. Go to `checkMemoryLimit()` function in `PhpReadinessCheck.php`, replace this code `$currentMemoryLimit = ini_get('memory_limit');` by `$currentMemoryLimit = '768M';`. Reload the Readiness Check to see the result :)

Comment: @GianniPasquali is it a fresh installation of Magento 2? If the above solution not work, let tweak the return array. `'warning' => $warning` => `'warning' => false`. The file is: `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php`

Comment: @Jami nothing... it seems that every change has no effect on this file, except to empty it,in that case the ReadinessCheck give ALL the errors and not only the memory...

Comment: I tryed to modify the code but nothing changed, I have to rebuild something? The file I changed is in "setup\src\Magento\Setup" dir

Comment: @GianniPasquali let download another Magento 2 package then try installing it again.That's the final solution :)

Comment: oh no... the site is online and full operative... the ReadinessCheck its needed only to install a SMTP extension because the email goes to spam! :(

Comment: Try removing all these folders in your magento/var folder: `var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*`. If the problem still be there, try exec this commands from your Magento root folder: `bin/magento cache:flush`, `bin/magento cron:run`, `php update/cron.php`, `bin/magento setup:cron:run`

Comment: YOU ARE A GURU! thanks! I have hacked the PhpReadinessCheck.php code adding: //$currentMemoryLimit = ini_get('memory_limit'); $currentMemoryLimit = '2000M'; then the point was the cron, so is need only to run bin/magento setup:cron:run to refresh the code!

Comment: Good to hear that @GianniPasquali! I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To increase your PHP memory limit:

1. Locate your php.ini file using the following command:

> `php --ini`

2. As a user with root privileges, use a text editor to open the php.ini specified by Loaded Configuration File.
3. Change `Locate memory_limit` to a value of 2GB for normal use and debugging.
   Save your changes to php.ini.
4. Restart your web server.

> CentOS `service httpd restart`
>
> Ubuntu `service apache2 restart`
>
> nginx (both CentOS and Ubuntu): `service nginx restart`

Try the installation again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tryed many times this method, it change the phpinfo() value but in the Readiness Check it give me always 128M!